How can I create a custom grant type in Keycloak?
I'm working on a project where I need to implement a custom grant type in Keycloak to meet specific authentication requirements. I've looked through the Keycloak documentation, but I'm having trouble understanding the exact steps needed to create and integrate a custom grant type. Can someone provide a detailed, step-by-step guide on how to accomplish this?
My requirement:
Sequence Diagram
Specifically, I need help with:
1. Writing the custom grant type class.
2. Registering the custom grant type in Keycloak.
3. Configuring the client and realm settings to use the custom grant type.
4. Testing the custom grant type to ensure it works as expected.
Any code examples, configuration tips, or references to relevant documentation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have found a refrence for my requiment but it is not helping much.
https://groups.google.com/g/keycloak-user/c/49UK73DMhfQ/m/q0SIx-vDBQAJ

There are several implementations of grant types coming with Keycloak out of the box. The code can be found here on git.
You can register the custom grant type by adding the SPI like it is done for every other Keycloak extension. See here for an example.
